# Showing that filtering a signal with bandwidth B with a brickwall filter of bandwidth W>B has no effect in time domain

Tags: filters, sampling, convolution, interpolation

The time-domain representation of $G(f) H(f)$, where $H(f)$ is an ideal brickwall filter of bandwidth $1/(2T)$ is:

$$
\int g(\tau) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-\tau}{T}\right) d\tau
$$

I want to show (using algebra, in the time domain) that the result of the above equation equals $g(t)$ if the bandwidth of $g$ is less than $1/(2T)$. This is something trivial to see in the frequency domain.

But how in the time domain, using convolution integrals?

By definition, if $g$ is bandlimited to $1/(2 T_g)$, I can expand it using the WKS interpolation formula, having the samples as coefficients:

$$
g(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} g(n T_g) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n T_g}{T_g}\right)
= \sum_{n-\infty}^{\infty} g[n] \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n T_g}{T_g}\right)
$$

Plugging this into the original equation:

$$
\int \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} g(n T_g) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{\tau-n T_g}{T_g}\right) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-\tau}{T}\right) d\tau \\
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} g(n T_g) \left[ \int \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{\tau-n T_g}{T_g}\right) \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-\tau}{T}\right) d\tau \right]
$$

From that, the term in bracket would need to be equivalent to $\operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n T_g}{T_g}\right)$ **if** $T \leq T_g$. But I don't see this working out

Comment: Isn't Whittaker only applicable when filtering a sampled signal? It seems from your question that $g(t)$ is continuous.

Comment: By definition, you can expand a bandlimited signal with the WKS interpolation formula by using its *samples* as the coefficients (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula). That's what I have done.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: Yeah -- it seems like you reduced the problem to showing that the sinc is unaffected by the filter. An idea: replace the sinc by its definition in terms of a sine, and see if that makes the integral tractable.

Comment: Maybe identity (31) can help here? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html

Comment: I have tried converting to sinusoids/expontentials but things get pretty messy and I don't see it going anywhere. What causes me most troubly is that there would need to be a condition like "if T<Tg, then everything reduces to a simple sinc". But I don't see how such a condition could work with sinusoids (I know that trigonometric functions can be simplified significantly when we assume integers -- periodicity -- but a mere greater/smaller comparison?

Comment: Identity (31) looks indeed extremely promising (as un-untuitive as it is). Where I get stuck with it is that the sinc's have different normalizations (T and Tg).

Comment: Yeah... you might have to post this in one of the math sites.